# Failing to establish a connection with a custom service

Tags: android, android-studio, arduino, bluetooth-lowenergy

I currently own a LilyPad Simblee BLE Board - RFD77101, with which I'm trying to establish a connection with a custom service that I am defining in arduino 1.6.5 IDE with the `Simblee.customUUID` command.

I later tried to get the service and the characteristic in Android Studio with the `BluetoothleGatt` sample code using the UUID I established previously.

The problem is when I connect to the Simblee the app fails to recognize the service and logs me the following error.

> Custom BLE Service not found

The code is kinda long hence I am not posting all of it directly. If anyone has an idea as to a solution to my problem and need and part of code I am obviously more than glad to post it.

Thanks to anyone in advance.

This is the public void where I attempt to obtain the characteristic:

```
public void readCustomCharacteristic() {
  if (mBluetoothAdapter == null || mBluetoothGatt == null) {
    Log.w(TAG, "BluetoothAdapter not initialized");
    return;
  }
  /*check if the service is available on the device*/
  BluetoothGattService mCustomService = mBluetoothGatt.getService(UUID.fromString("fe84-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb"));
  if(mCustomService == null) {
    Log.w(TAG, "Custom BLE Service not found");
    return;
  }
  /*get the read characteristic from the service*/
  BluetoothGattCharacteristic mReadCharacteristic = mCustomService.getCharacteristic(UUID.fromString("2d30c083-f39f-4ce6-923f-3484ea480596"));
  if(!mBluetoothGatt.readCharacteristic(mReadCharacteristic)) {
    Log.w(TAG, "Failed to read characteristic");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
BluetoothGattService mCustomService = mBluetoothGatt.getService(UUID.fromString("fe84-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb"));
```

The UUID you provided is not in correct format. According to the documentation, the part before first hyphen should consist of 4 hex octets (See the one you provided for characteristics) but you only got 2 here. You should add padding 0 in front like

```
BluetoothGattService mCustomService = mBluetoothGatt.getService(UUID.fromString("0000fe84-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb"));
```

---

Edit : Missing a point here. Have you called mBluetoothGatt.discoverServices()?

Comment: With adding the "0000" padding and changing the characteristic uuid to "2d30c08**2**..." (Which is the read characteristic of the Simblee module) ended up working fine now. Thanks